# Set component key equal to path parameter in Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a route defined as follows:

```js
<Route exact path="/licenses/:type?" component={Licenses} />
```

I want my component to re-render when the type parameter changes, so, as mentioned in react-router documentation, I need to use a key. I want the value of key same as param passed to the route. Something like:

```js
<Route exact path="/licenses/:type?" key=":type" component={Licenses} />
```

But I am unable to get the value of the type parameter as key. Is there any way to set the key same as type parameter's value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Got it!

I should use `render` instead of `component` like this:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/licenses/:type?"
  render={props => <Licenses key={props.match.params.type || 'empty'} /> }
/>
```

Comment: is this valid for react router 3?

Comment: @Allison i am currently using react-router 4. It is working fine. But i am not sure for react-router 3. You can give it a try. Thanks.